# Parsing Valuable information from javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is my scenario

A user uses some credits, they win or lose, either way, the credits they now have will be updated on a database since Javascript can't use MySQL I could parse the data through javascript into PHP.

The only thing is, I don't know if this is secure if I do it through AJAX.
Is there any other secure method of transferring 'credits'?

Comment: The way you can make something secure as Javascript calls your PHP, which makes changes to your database, is to ensure all validation is done at the very least in your serverside code (your PHP). In your PHP code, you want to authenticate who the user is, and perform all actions only upon the user they are.

So if you have `jack` using a credit, your javascript might call your server (PHP) with a `/consumeCredit/` request, and in your PHP, you would resolve the user (`jack`, who is user #123) and then perform your database update of removing 3 `credits` from `jacks` account

Comment: Essentially, assume the worst, and assume that people will be modifying your clientside (javascript) code (because they can and will) to try manipulate variables. Never, ever, take in a parameter of `userId` that might let a hacker try impersonate someone else, always figure out who the user is on the serverside code (PHP) and validate any inputs coming in. For example, if you have a PHP action like `/giveCredits?amount=3`, that `3` is most likely coming clientside and could be manipulated by the user, so validate whether the number `3` is even possible or makes sense.

Comment: Without code to examine it's really hard to say for sure. You'll need to do HTTPS at the absolute minimum. Beyond that it's application-level security.

Comment: There is no security issues with "using ajax", as long as you use it properly.

Comment: Tor, what do you mean by Call request consumeCredits?
Like maybe send their new total credits to a variable in PHP page using ajax, the credit variable of which is set in PHP so it cannot be edited.